# How to validate recurrence string following standard rfc2445

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, rfc2445, ical4j

I am workgin with google calendar api and I am using iCal4j to generate recurrence string. I would use this library also to check a string that should contain a recurrence string. How I can do that?
There is an other way to do?
Thank you a lot for any Help
Alberto :)

Answer (score 0):

If the string contains only the RRULE value, then, you can use the net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.RRule(String value) constructor or net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Recur(String value) constructor and check for exceptions.

`new Recur("FREQ=somejunk")` will throw an IllegalArgumentException while

`new Recur("FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=bogus")` will throw a ParseException

Comment: thanks! Then I supposed there are no method returing a boolean to ask if a string is a valid rrule or not. Something strange also : I check RRule code and there is a validate method, private :( not implemented